# StrongLoop loopback - how to exclude results without related model results

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, database-relations

I'm using this Node API JSON, which returns Customers, their instances, and the instance versions.

```
Customers.find({
    "include": {
        "relation": "instances",
        "scope": {
            "include": {
                "relation": "versions"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I would like to exclude all customers which do not have any related instances, in the result JSON, there is an "instances" entry with empty [ ]. however when I try to use this in a "where" I get a server error... any ideas, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: What is *the instance version*? Is it a model with a relation defined to customer?

Comment: Yes, customer model has many instances, instance model has many versions. The above JSON is working, but I want to exclude all customers that do not have instances.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MongoDB as your database, then you could add a `where` property to your filter at the same level as your first include, like:

```
var filter = {
    where: {
        relationId: {
            exists: false
        }
    },
    include: {...}
};
Customers.find(filter, function ( err, results ) {...});
```

See issue [#1009](http://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1009#issuecomment-85567830%20%22#1009) for details/updates re: database implementation.

Alternatively, you could just [filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) the results with Lodash:

```
var customersWithInstances = _.filter( customers, function ( customer )
{
    return customer.instanceId;
});
```